# How do I validate a form and redirect to a specific URL based on the user's answers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, user-input

```
<form>
  <p class="question"> Hold Old are you</p>
  <p ><input name="1"  type="radio" value="15"> 12</p>
  <p ><input name="1"  type="radio" value="8"> 45</p>
  <p ><input name="1"  type="radio" value="2"> 23</p>  
  <p class="question"> What is you name<p/>  
  <p ><input name="2"  type="radio" > Jerry</p>
  <p ><input name="2"  type="radio" > Tom</p>
  <p ><input name="2"  type="radio" > Becky</p>  
  <p class="question"> Are you single</p>
  <p ><input name="3"  type="radio" > yes</p>
  <p ><input name="3"  type="radio" > no</p>
  <p ><input name="4"  type="radio" > married</p>  
</form>
```

Hello How are you?

I have a form here that ask 3 questions and each have 3 answers has a point and there will be a score:

if the score is >= 91, then after submitting it should take them to 90.html page

if the score is < 90 And  >= 21) then after submitting it should take them to 20.html page

if the score is <= 20) then it should take them to the below20.html

the form should validate to make sure all question have an answer chosen

I need some direction on how i should set this up

HELP please thanks

Comment: Are you really only allowed to be 12, 23 or 45 years old, and be named Jerry, Tom or Becky? Aren't married and "no, not single" the same thing? :)

Comment: well you have to be one, but each have a point.

Comment: @Robert - It depends how many points you get for being married vs "no".  That's the really interesting part of this question...

Comment: Here is a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/NLJvZ/

Comment: @Simeon: Since there really does appear to be an actual answer to this question, I've reopened it.  Go ahead and post your answer, and I'll upvote it.  Be sure to copy the code into your answer.

Comment: this is perfect!!! but seems not to be directing perfectly..


but im doing some testing on my local end...my task is larger, but this is a perfect starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you're looking for. Here is a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/NLJvZ/

```
var $rs = $(':radio');

$(':button').click(function(){
    var $ch = $(':radio:checked');
    if($ch.length < 3)
        alert('Please answer all questions');
    else{
        var score = 0;

        $ch.each(function(){
            score += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        });

        var url = 'below20.html';

        if(score >= 91)
            url = '90.html';
        else if(score < 90 && score >= 21)
            url = '20.html';

        alert('Going to URL: ' + url);
        location.href = url;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="question1">
    <h3>What is your name?</h3>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="first1" value="1" />
        Tom
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="first2" value="3" />
        Jerry
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="first3" value="2" />
        Becky
    </label>
</div>
<br />
<div id="question2">
    <h3>Are you single?</h3>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="second1" value="1" />
        Yes
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="second2" value="3" />
        No
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="second3" value="2" />
        Married
    </label>
</div>
<br />
<div id="question3">
    <h3>How old are you?</h3>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="third" value="1" />
        12
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="third" value="3" />
        23
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="third" value="2" />
        45
    </label>
</div>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: this is good, but how come all of them goes to below20.html ??

Comment: @user634599: Because you didn't tell us how to score the answers.  Just add more code that does this.

Comment: Hey Simeons Thanks a lot..i added some code on to it..Thanks a lot again!! seems to me working!!

Comment: It's the value on the type="radio" inputs that determines the score count on each answer. Adjust that to your needs :) And please accept my answer if it was what you were looking for!